# Mail send blank messages with correct post data?

Tags: php, html, email, sendmail

So when I send a email with a form (POST) I send the email fine, but when I get it it is blank (except for the parts defined in php.  Like its not getting my POST data, when I know it is.

PHP:

```
$parentName  = strip_tags($_POST['parentName']);
$studentName = strip_tags($_POST['studentName']);
$grade       = strip_tags($_POST['grade']);
$message     = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
$to          = "email@email.com";
$subject     = "Message From, ".$parentName;
$message     = "Student: ".$studentName."Grade: ".$grade."\r\n".$message;
$from        = "Message System";
$headers     = "From:" . $parentName;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="php/syst.php" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="parentName" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Parent Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="parentName" name="parentName" placeholder="John Doe"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">    
     <label for="studentName" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Student Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="studentName" name="studentName" placeholder="John Doe"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="grade" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Grade</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="grade" name="grade" placeholder="9 - 12"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="message" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Message</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7"><textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message"></textarea></div>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<center>
    <div class="opit">
     <img id="loading" src="png/loa.gif">
    <button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
    </div>
    </center>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: What do you get when you `echo strip_tags($_POST['message']);` ?

Comment: I don't get anything.

Comment: As Fluffeh said try echo or another function, maybe var_dump will work better. Also good is to use some dubugger so you will see your variables. I use Netbeans and xdebug.

Comment: I get: string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" with var_dumb

Comment: @TimO'Connell If echo'ing doesn't show anything, then neither is the mail message. For some reason that isn't apparent in the code provided, your POSTS aren't being passed properly. If you can't echo it, chances are small that it will be visible in an email.

Comment: @TimO'Connell Are you redirecting to get to the PHP code perhaps? Any fancy JS running on the form that alters the data in any way?

Comment: @Fluffy how would I fix this?

Comment: There is but its not done, don't worry about it its all just tied up because my client needs this done fast then I can add some AJax later. so yea, there was @Fluffy

Comment: @TimO'Connell There is a redirect, or there is JS? I just want to put this to bed, drop an answer in so that we can close the question to save other folks dropping in and trying to solve something that is already resolved.

Comment: @TimO'Connell I popped in an answer that will hopefully close off this question. Please feel free to edit it as you see fit in case I missed the exact reason this data wasn't being passed to the PHP as expected.

Comment: @Tim O'Connell try to post the whole php file here

Comment: @TimO'Connell This `$headers = "From:" . $parentName;` will not be from an `email` but the "Parent's name". There should be an Email field they need to fill and then you'd need to change that after to `$headers     = "From:" . $email;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering based on the comment train under the question itself.

When a form is submitted, the POST/GET data is sent to the server. If the server redirects to another page however, that data is lost unless the redirecting script is written to pass that information forward.

If you want to redirect through a header or the like to another bit of code somewhere, you need to process the POST/GET information - which is itself part of the header!

On the flipside, be careful with JavaScript playing with form data prior to submitting the form. An overzealous script can easily or accidentally wipe out any form data, then merrily continue on with the form being submitted - and giving a great headache trying to troubleshoot the issue in the server code. A great way to troubleshoot this is to have the function drop spout up an alert that shows the data being submitted AFTER it has made any changes.